# Bug with Check for Matching Contact(s) button

Tags: contacts, duplicate-contacts

Following the upgrade to 5.3.0, we are finding that the 'Check for Matching Contacts' button, which is in the edit contact screen, is not working. The screen refreshes and reloads the same contact, with no error message.

If you run the default supervised rule from the 'Find and Merge Duplicate Contacts' screen, it picks the duplicate up.  But the Check for Matching Contacts function has stopped working.  Is this a bug anyone else is seeing?

Thank you!

Robin

Drupal 7

Comment: Are you seeing proposed matches pop up as you type? There was a change in this functionality

Comment: I tested on dmaster at "https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/add?reset=1&ct=Individual" by typing 'betty adams' and got "Similar Contacts Found
If the contact you were trying to add is listed below, click their name to view or edit their record:
Betty Jensen jensen.betty87@fakemail.biz
Mrs. Betty Adams bettyadams@wisconsinactionfund.org" - but yes if I then click on "Check for Matching Contacts" it just reloads the page without the pop up. Does the pop up not give you the info you need and hence the 'check for matching contacts' is now a bit redundant?

Comment: We do see the pop-up duplicates warning when adding contacts in the admin interface.... BUT The duplicates are actually being created unsupervised, by users booking for events - we then go in and manually de-dupe.  This may seem odd, but we have found it is the best way for our organisation. I wonder if the change in this functionality  has broken the button, thank you for confirming it doesn't work for you either @petednz-fuzion

Comment: IN terms of duplicates being created - do you need to a/ review your Dedupe rules, b/ confirm which dedupe rules are being applied for each Event

Comment: I think Coleman is working on a patch for this - it has been discussed in the dev-post-release channel.

Note that under Administer CiviCRM>>Customise Data and screens>>Display Preferences you can opt for Check for Similar Contacts While Typing and they will pop up on name or email match as you do data entry.

We also have a hook that adds a link to find matches by rule to the actions on the contact summary screen

Comment: hook looks like 
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coleman recently pushed a [fix](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12552) for this on git. Can you please apply [the patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12552.diff) and QA if it fixes your problem(if so please comment on PR about your QA result)

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks Pradeep! Great to know it is an identified bug. I've applied the patch and I'm afraid it *didn't* work for me, I see the same behaviour. (Page refreshes on a known duplicate with no error message).  Having also now disabled the AJAX check while typing, it now works, but the patch did not work for me with duplicate checking "while typing" enabled. Happy to be part of any further testing

Comment: Must be worth discussing on PR https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12552

Comment: see https://lab.civicrm.org/eileen/Product-maintenance/issues/14

Answer (score 1):

the hook per comments looks like
hook looks like

````
```
/**
 * Add dedupe searches to actions available.
 *
 * @param array $actions
 * @param int $contactID
 */
function dedupetools_civicrm_summaryActions(&$actions, $contactID) {
  try {
    $ruleGroups = civicrm_api3('RuleGroup', 'get', array(
      'contact_type' => civicrm_api3('Contact', 'getvalue' , array('id' => $contactID, 'return' => 'contact_type')),
    ));
    $weight = 500;

    $contactIDS = array($contactID);
    foreach ($ruleGroups['values'] as $ruleGroup) {
      $actions['otherActions']['dupe' . $ruleGroup['id']] = array(
        'title' => ts('Find matches using Rule : %1', array(1 => $ruleGroup['title'])),
        'name' => ts('Find matches using Rule : %1', array(1 => $ruleGroup['title'])),
        'weight' => $weight,
        'ref' => 'dupe-rule crm-contact_activities-list',
        'key' => 'dupe' . $ruleGroup['id'],
        'href' => CRM_Utils_System::url('civicrm/contact/dedupefind', array(
          'reset' => 1,
          'action' => 'update',
          'rgid' => $ruleGroup['id'],
          'criteria' => json_encode(array('contact' => array('id' => array('IN' => $contactIDS)))),
          'limit' => count($contactIDS),
        )),
      );
      $weight++;
    }
  }
  catch (CiviCRM_API3_Exception $e) {
    // This would most likely happen if viewing a deleted contact since we are not forcing
    // them to be returned. Keep calm & carry on.
  }
}

```
````